# How to enable user shell?

Tags: linux, permissions, file-permissions, usermode

I was checking users permissons with

```
less /etc/passwd

cassandra:x:123:130:Cassandra database,,,:/var/lib/cassandra:/bin/false
```

I want to unlock the account.

How to do this with `usermod` or in any other manner?

Comment: man usermod, `usermod -U`.

Comment: @LuisMuñoz No,it does not work,sudo usermod -U cassandra,stays the same.

Comment: Why do you think the account is locked? add details to your question please.